# Would this experiment disprove/prove that consciousness causes collapse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

A double slit experiment, is taking place. There are detectors, placed inside both of the slits. On the first run if a particle travels through one of the slits, the detector registers, that it has detected a particle, but doesn't specify which slit it has travelled through(to the conscious experimenter). Moreover, the potential for having knowledge as to which slit the particle went through is totally removed since the detector, is set up in such a manor that it is only possible to know that a particle was detected and not which slit it went through. On the second run of the experiment, however, the potential for the experimenter to know which slit it went through is given, by the detector revealing which slit it went through(which would in turn give the experimenter, the potential to know which slit). If there is no interference pattern there on the second run, but on the first run, this would imply, that consciousness causes collapse, since it shows when the potential for human knowledge is there the particle collapses to an eigenstate, as opposed to not collapsing to an eigenstate, on the first run, when a measurement is being made but without the potential for a conscious observer to know the result. Would this prove or disprove(in principle) that consciousness causes collapse?

Comment: If the detector is set up in such a manner that it doesn't extract which-path information, then how does it reveal which slit the particle went through in the second run? It seems like you have changed the way the detector interacts with the particle in between runs.

Comment: have a look https://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html

Comment: so would it work then?

Comment: the link I gave says that the "detector" one uses, changes the quantum mechanical problem from "electron scattering off two slits of given width and separation" to "electron scattering off two slits of give width and separation + filter",a different problem. *" Although the electrons (which were shot one by one) could still pass through the filtered slit, the filter caused more of the electrons to undergo inelastic scattering rather than elastic scattering. As the physicists explained,*

Comment: *an electron undergoing inelastic scattering is localized at the covered slit, and acts like a spherical wave after passing through the slit"*